# How to perform select query on integer field in SQLite, Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectAll + DatabaseSchema.Vehicles.TABLE_NAME + " where " + DatabaseSchema.Vehicles.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Here, `selectAll = "select * from "`, and `COLUMN_ID` is has int datatype. This code returns an empty cursor everytime. Even though data is inserted in table.
When I run query with only "`select * from tablename`". It gives me data.

Comment: Is there any row which has the passed id value in its COLUMN_ID field?

Comment: I didn't get your question exactly. COLUMN_ID is int primary key. It is auto-incremented.

Comment: do you have a row with COLUMN_ID == id ?

Comment: yes. it exists. i'm trying to access first record only with COLUMN_ID == 0. (id = 0, which is there in db) with where clause but curser is empty.

Comment: it's a variable, selectAll = "select * from ".

Comment: My comment = Blackbelt's one

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is when you are accesing with `cursor.moveToFirst();` try this instead:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectAll + DatabaseSchema.Vehicles.TABLE_NAME + " where " + DatabaseSchema.Vehicles.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    //Do your stuff!
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: when I try to retrieve by column which are "text" as datatype in db, it returns me rows of the result. but in case of "int" as datatype, it gives me empty cursor.